# Validation of viewstate MAC failed with SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, master-pages, viewstate, hidden-field

I'm getting stuck into this viewstate problem with my SharePoint 2010 application.

Currently I created a custom master page which use my Custom Control named Navigation. The Navigation control HTML just contains 3 Hidden Fields in order to store data.

When I apply the master page for my site, I created a List and then add a Three-State work flow to the list. After selecting Three-State workflow at the Add a Workflow screen (/_layouts/Addwrkfl.aspx), I click OK to submit.

Then I got this error message

**Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.**

**Stack Trace:**

```
[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 192.168.149.149
    Port: 56086
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
    ViewState: /wEWBAKi+o3/DAKVnOnXCwKa66m6DgKoxMKWBhUcn2XAshDSDMZdpDN35fWC8RHp
    Referer: `http://localhost/_layouts/Addwrkfl.aspx?List=%7B2897B53B%2D16AF%2D47A9%2DB963%2DC9501432C5CA%7D`
    Path: /_layouts/ItemRWfAssoc.aspx]
[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +148
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +10977361
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureEventValidationFieldLoaded() +205
```

*

I also removed all of the code behind of the Navigation control but the issue still appeared. It seems that the error appear before any C# code is executed.

If I tried to remove the 3 Hidden Field from the Navigation control, the issue went away.

Any one could help me with this issue?
Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

FYI, I don't host my application using Web Farm

Answer (score 0):

I received this error on my SP 2010 farm after I added some custom delegate control to run in master page. The control had server side text box, and some other html elements, when I switched the asp:textbox to html input the problem was gone